# How can I connect SSH server in shared hosting in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ssh, server, hosting, shared-hosting, openssh

I want to connect SSH server(**Shared hosting server**) though ubuntu terminal and also installed openssh-server but I not able connect when I enter the SSH details got error like connection timeout or host unreachale.

I have these SSH details.
**username

SSH hosting 

SSH port

link

port

and password

private key(PPK file).**

I refereed  following commands but still not connect.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-to-connect-to-remote-server-linux-or-windows

Hope you can help me though these point.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your public key has been registered on the remote server `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

But first, you will need to [convert your putty key to OpenSSH](https://www.simplified.guide/putty/convert-ppk-to-ssh-key), using puttygen ([as in here](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/putty-ppk-vers-openssl-openssh.html)).

Then, register the public key to the remote server, using the username/password to open an interactive session and modifying the remote   `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
After that, you should not be using the password again (unless it was not a password, but the private putty key *passphrase*)